# Adempiere Multiple Display Logic

Tags: adempiere

I have column called `Name` and it shows up when

```
1. Column ISADMIN = Y AND AD_User_ID = 1000002
2. Column ISADMIN = Y AND AD_User_ID = 1000003
3. Column ISADMIN = N
```

So, when column `ISADMIN = Y` but `AD_User_ID` is not equal to `1000002` nor `1000003`, column `Name` can't be shown.

I have tried `@ISADMIN@=Y&@#AD_User_ID@=1000002| @ISADMIN@=Y&@#AD_User_ID@=1000003 | @ISADMIN@=N` but it still won't work

Any alternatives?

Comment: To clarify; 1) ISPPHP should read ISADMIN? 2) ISADMIN can be Y OR N only? 3) did you restart the server after making AD changes?

Comment: @ColinRooney I am sorry, made a typo, ISPPHP should be ISADMIN. Yes, ISADMIN can be Y or N only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Display Logic in Adempiere can be tricky because there is, to my knowledge, no syntax for grouping logic tests (with brackets for example) just the basic left to right evaluation. So you have to create the tests carefully sometimes using expressions that are not immediately obvious.

So maybe

```
@ISADMIN@=N | @#AD_User_ID@>1000001 & @#AD_User_ID@<1000004
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Colin Rooney is right there is no grouping available with bracket.
Keep in the mind that adempiere execute this condition from left to right. So you should right condition according to it.

So according to me it is right.